# ng not found even if @angular/cli is global and located in environment variables

Tags: node.js, angular-cli, npm-install

I have `node.js version 16.14.2` and `npm version 8.5.0` and also `@angular/cli@13.3.0` I can verify that `npm` and `node` is working however `@angular/cli` that was installed globally can not be found using the `ng` command. I can also confirm that my environment variables are well set in place. But the main problem is that I still can't call the `ng` command.

[image]

P.S. pay no attention to ng@.0.0.0 I tried doing `npm install -g ng`

[image]

Comment: You really can follow this video, I hope that is helpful for you:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JV4EUBD9u-0&ab_channel=ComputerProgramming

Answer (score 2):

- Uninstall "angular cli" and "ng".
- Then run the command `npm install -g @angular/cli`